# How to fill tuple with result of calculation from template arguments parameter packs?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to do some calculations on my template arguments and insert them into a tuple and return them. I cannot seem to get the syntax right though. Is it possible?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/1naxYWPhx)

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <typename TupleT, int ...values>
auto create_tuple() {
    // Fold expressions does not seem to work
    // return TupleT{((values + 1) , ...)};

    // This does not work either
    // return TupleT{(values + 1) , ...};

    // Expected result
    // return TupleT{1 + 1, 1 + 2}

}

int main() {
    auto t = create_tuple<std::tuple<int, int>, 1, 2>(); // Usage, cannot be changed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just an ordinary parameter pack that gets passed to a constructor.

```
return TupleT{(values + 1)...};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c5v9bPWjn)

Comment: When you think you have tested all the possible combinations... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `std::make_tuple(...)`, I find it expressive and clean:

```
return std::make_tuple((values + 1)...);
```

Comment: Yes, in my case it would not work, but generally that could be a good solution before c++17, nowdays you could just use the constructor?

Comment: why does it not work, this works all new versions [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T1fcx1KKn).

Comment: It works in godbolt, but it does not work in my usecase. The tuple was a toy example to ask the question, in my case I use a struct, but the accepted answer still works for me, and your answer is a good references if anyone want to initialize a tuple.

Comment: And `return std::tuple{(values + 1)...};` (without make_) would also works in >c++17. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W5fP4nrWs)

Comment: Well you asked `How to fill tuple` there is no way for me to know that you are talking about a different type to fill ([XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)). `make_tuple` was made to quickly create tuples without having to name all templates like `std::tuple<int, int, double>{ 1, 2, 5.0; }`

Comment: That's why I told you that it was a possible answer to the general question. Yes I know about the history for make_tuple, but with c++17 it is no longer needed. Someone will probably be helped by your answers as well, thats the positive thing with Stackoverflow, right?

Seriously, is it possible to ask questions here without somebody getting upset?

Comment: I don't know why you would assume this.